# Frequency domain spline approximation and B-Spline inverse transforms

Tags: linear-transformations, fourier-analysis, spline

In short, I would like pointers to closed-form formulas, or efficient algorithms for computing the *inverse* of ether sine, cosine, or Hartley transforms of the B-Spline basis. The motivation, as explained below, comes from approximating the frequency domain of functions of bounded frequency.

### Motivation

It is well known that splines, and in particular cubic splines, have good approximation properties in bounded intervals. I would like to use splines to use them in the *frequency domain* to approximate real-valued functions of bounded frequency, either on the positive numbers, or the entire real-line. Since splines are meant, first and foremost, for real numbers, I would like to concentrate on real (rather than complex) domains and look at things like the [sine/cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms), or [Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform) transforms.

Suppose that $B_1, \dots, B_n$ is a B-Spline basis defined on some real interval of the form $[0, \tau]$ for sine/cosine transforms or $[-\tau, \tau]$ for Hartley transform. The transform of the function I would like to approximate is:
$$
T[f](\omega) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n a_i B_i(\omega)
$$
Thus, my function becomes
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i T^{-1}[B_i](x)
$$

Comment: The splines become just finite linear combinations of delta-measures and their derivatives after a few differentiations and the inverse Fourier transforms of those are simple explicit rational functions times exponents. Is that representation not satisfactory for you for any reason? If so, why?

Comment: Can you share an explicit formula?